# Convert hours into seconds con pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have hours extracted from the timestamp of my dataframe by the command lines:

```
import pandas as pd  
from datetime import *  
from datetime import datetime  
import datetime as dt  
import time  

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])  
df['time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.time  
df['time']

Output: id      time
        3539    23:49:58  
        3540    23:52:39  
        3541    23:55:19  
        3542    23:58:00  
        Name: time, dtype: object
```

I need to convert time column into seconds, i.e. 
23:49:58 = 23*3600+49*60+58 = 85798 seconds

```
id   time
3539 85798
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Make sure to add what you have tried so far and what went wrong. Also try to include output and/or errors so we can better help you. Remember, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, but there are a lot of helpful people here that are willing to take a look if you make an effort to explain your problem.

Comment: Sorry! I did so many attempts by googling and reading about time series conversion that was too long to report all them here. Therefore I decided to put just the problem and assuming that I spent the whole morning trying to fix this. 
Next time will make sure to do that for a simpler problem or a doubt. Sorry again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert datetimes to `hour`s, `minute`s and `second`s:

```
df['time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour * 3600 + 
             df['timestamp'].dt.minute * 60 + 
             df['timestamp'].dt.second
```

Or [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and get [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
               .dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':['2015-04-01 23:49:58','2016-04-01 23:49:58']})
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])  
print (df)
            timestamp
0 2015-04-01 23:49:58
1 2016-04-01 23:49:58

df['time1'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour * 3600 + \
              df['timestamp'].dt.minute * 60 + \
              df['timestamp'].dt.second

df['time2'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
                 .dt.total_seconds().astype(int))
print (df)
            timestamp  time1  time2
0 2015-04-01 23:49:58  85798  85798
1 2016-04-01 23:49:58  85798  85798
```

Comment: Excellent! Actually my main problem was to handle with object and deltatime types that used make me fail when I used total-seconds() and to_timedelta. Thanks a lot Jezrael!

Comment: pls could I ask a short clarification about the df['time2'] line? My understanding is that you converted timestamp in timedelta, than in string and then in number?... not familiar enough with dt.strftime and .astype. 

My problem was that to_timedelta converted into object that made me fail  by using total_seconds().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly. Now I am thinking a bit about this, and first solution should be faster in larger data.

Comment: Great! Thanks again!